# Theme neptune doesn't apply

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gxt, uibinder

I want to apply the neptune theme on my application GWT but it's not working.

I already added theme neptune.jar and theme builder to dependences:
my app.gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme' />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML"/>
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
<inherits name='org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.OpenLayers' />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="FALSE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED"/>
<set-configuration-property name="locale.cookie" value="GWT_LOCALE" />

<entry-point class='org.traccar.web.client.Traccar'/>

<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
```

And my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gxt-themebuilder</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gxt-theme-neptune</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme' />` to after the `inherits` for `GXT` - if you put it earlier, it gets overridden by the default.